# Input output block in matlab simulink

Tags: matlab

which block should i used for creating input and output pins in matlab simulink for sending and recieving signals.I tried using signal builder but not getting the desired output.

Comment: Please show us your code what have you done so far.

Comment: how do i attach a file here?